# Pages published last year that still generate traffic

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

is it possible to get in some way the published date of a page with Analytics?
I want to understand which pages published 1 years ago generated traffic in the last month.

Maybe something like `views on day[x] = 0 && views on day[x+1] > 0`, but how?
Do I need to use Analytics API?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Go to behaviour, all website content. Select the page in question. Select a very long timeframe from the datepicker. Look at the graph at the top to see at which point traffic starts (if you mouse over the first point where graph goes up you'll get a tooltip that displayse the date).

Comment: But I don't know the page in question. I would like to know the Top 10 pages (published 1 year ago) that generated views in the last month